# Javascript with Array of Objects; Property in Object has Value, returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

So basically I have an array of objects with properties. Now the array is 102 elements long from a particular dataset that I am testing with. #'s 4 and 6 in the array come through fine but 5 has an issue. I have checked this site and many others and I've found one instance of the exact issue, their solution to use property notation did not work.

When I check questionList[5]['id'] it returns "undefined", same with questionList[5].id. I don't understand why. Here is the object that is the problem:

```
questionList[5]: Object
    id: "questionPage-6"
    attached: ""
    options: Array[4]
    required: true
    text: "How often do all of your active members meet?"
    type: "dropdown"
    value: ""
```

Whereas this question right after it:

```
questionList[6]: Object
    attached: ""
    id: "questionPage-7"
    required: true
    text: "How are these meeting successful and how could they be improved?"
    type: " textarea"
    value: ""
```

When I do questionList[6]['id'] I get "questionPage-7".

Because 5's id is undefined I can't create the tabs in jQuery UI that I'm trying to create, I get bad fragment identifiers because the div id that uses the id is set as #undefined.

Comment: PS - ALL the other elements work just fine. 5 for some reason is broken.

Comment: Could you put together a jsfiddle showing the error?

Comment: Can you please show the code that creates this array of objects? What you show above is not JS - is that what shows in the browser console or something?

Comment: How is the array being initialized? Do you have raw JSON for it? How was the object value above printed?

Comment: This is coming from a json string, not being generated.

[check out the JSON array](http://pastebin.com/piFeUyEe)

Comment: I copied the object values from Firebug.

Comment: @ColinKnapp Might have been nicer to format it.

Comment: Hah my bad...

[FORMATTED JSON ARRAY](http://pastebin.com/1kWzA4LZ)

Comment: Seeing it formatted I think I found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your raw JSON has the id property of the element at index 5 with a space, that is it has `" id"` instead of `"id"`.

Demo showing it works if you use `questionList[5][" id"]`: http://jsfiddle.net/VYwYC/

(Obviously you need to fix the source of the JSON.)